# Android application throwing null on SetContentView

Tags: android

I have a pretty simple application right now. Here is the main Activity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    connectButton = (ConnectButton) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    connectButton.init(this, facebook, new String [] { "publish_stream",
            "friends_about_me" });

}
```

And here is part of the R.java class

```
public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
```

and the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 

   <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/facebookconnect" android:id="@+id/connect" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>

   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i click on the application from the AVD, it throws an error and makes me force close the application.  It is throwing a null pointer at the SetContentView(R.layout.main).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: When i stopped working on it for a little while, closed eclipse, started it back up, the null pointer wasn't being thrown anymore...strange

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project. In eclipse go to Project --> Clean...

Comment: Tried this. And closing and restarting eclipse. Both tasks didn't seem to help